# Why does "awk ... file | tee file" truncate the file?

Tags: text-processing, awk

Why does this pipeline truncate the file:

```
awk '...' file | tee file
```

while `cat`ing it first doesn't?

```
cat file | awk '...' | tee file
```

---

The file is just a regular config file with hundreds of lines. And I use `tee` to avoid using `sponge` (as I have to install `moreutils` first).

Comment: I would simplify the task `head -1 file | tee -a file` with utils `cat`, `head`, `tail`

Comment: How big was the file? If the file is say 100k do you still find that `cat`ing the file avoids truncation? If you have `more-utils` package installed, why do you think someone wrote `sponge`? If the file is small, do you expect `awk '...' file | { sleep 2 ; tee file}` to work any better?

Comment: @icarus It's a config file. I want to modify the config file across machines and it's not guaranteed that they have `more-utils` installed. So I use `tee` as `awk` cannot do inplace operation like `sed`'s `-i`

Comment: @nezabudka I think you missed the point. It's not about appending something, it's doing some operation in the file using `awk` then save it.

Comment: @annahri, I see. I just gave an example without an unnecessary pipline, and the options you can omit at all

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will find over the long run that this behavior is not consistent.

The problem is, that `tee` at some point in time opens the file for writing. From that moment on, the file is truncated. That is independent of which program reads the file.

It just happens that `cat` is very quick and that the reading of the file apparently has been finished before `tee` opens the file. But if for example the system load is bigger, `cat` may not have been finished, and the pipeline with `cat` may also truncate.

So, do not write to the same file as you are reading your pipeline from. Instead use Gnu `awk`'s `-i inplace`, or if that is not available on your system, use

```
cp file file.tmp &&
awk '...' file.tmp | tee file
```

Comment: Note that `gawk -i` does not work as `gsed -i`. The `-i` option to `gawk` takes an argument (a library to load). Using it to load the `inline` library will make edits happen in-line:  `gawk -i inline ...`.

Comment: @Kusalananda it is `inplace` not `inline` as far as I know

Comment: @Sundeep You are correct, it is `inplace`.

Comment: If you don't add a `&&` at the end of the `cp` line then you'll zap `file` if the `cp` failed. Note that this breaks awks ability to print the original file name and it leaves the tmp file lying around after you're done with it so I'd actually use `awk '...' file | tee file.tmp && mv file.tmp file` instead.

Comment: @EdMorton: if this is in a script, you are absolutely right. But then, why would you use `tee` like this?

Comment: @LjmDullaart it doesn't make any difference if it's in a script file or on the command line. You'd use `tee` so you can see the awk output on your screen as it's being written to the file, not sure if you had something else in mind with that question

Comment: @EdMorton The difference is that if you work interactively, you see if the copy fails and you will be able to correct it (before you issue the `awk`). Then an `and` is not necessary.